# How do I install the termlib library on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: compiling

I am trying to compile a program on Ubuntu 20.04 and the make command ends with the following errors.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltermlib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:576: Sysunix] Error 1
```

I have already installed : buildessentials, llibcurses

What do I need to do to install the termlib library ?

Comment: What is `termlib`? What is `sysunix`? Which program are you trying to compile? Where its source code is located?

Comment: I assume that termlib refers to the library used to do screen manipulation. I just checked "Sysunix" and it happens to be an empty file. The source code I got by extracing files from a TAR archive for the game named Nethack

Comment: Then you have to know that NetHack is [packaged for Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/nethack). All you need is to install its packages with `sudo apt-get install nethack-console` (console version) and/or `sudo apt-get install nethack-x11` (GUI X11).

Comment: that worked nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Then you have to know that NetHack is [packaged for Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/nethack).

All you need is to install its packages with

- `sudo apt-get install nethack-console` (console version)

and/or

- `sudo apt-get install nethack-x11` (GUI X11).

Comment: I got here because of the title (I'm trying to build something else - not nethack - that needs `-ltermlib` -- any ideas?